# Can't access $axios in NuxtJS Store

Tags: nuxt.js, store

I'm trying to make a auth system with NuxtJS.
But, I can't access this.$axios (like the doc said https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage)

Here is my code :

```
export const state = () => ({
  token: process.browser ? localStorage.getItem('jwt') || null : null,
  status: ''
})

export const getters = () => ({
  isAuthenticated: state => !!state.token,
  authStatus: state => state.status
})

export const actions = {
  AUTH_REQUEST: ({commit, dispatch}, user) => {
    console.log(this.$store)
    console.log(this.$axios)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // The Promise used for router redirect in login
      commit('AUTH_REQUEST')
      this.$axios({url: 'authentication_token', data: user, method: 'POST'})
        .then(resp => {
          const token = resp.data.token
          localStorage.setItem('jwt', token) // store the token in localstorage
          commit('AUTH_SUCCESS', token)
          // you have your token, now log in your user :)
          dispatch('USER_REQUEST')
          resolve(resp)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          commit('AUTH_ERROR', err)
          localStorage.removeItem('jwt') // if the request fails, remove any possible user token if possible
          reject(err)
        })
    })
  }
}


export const mutations = {
  AUTH_REQUEST: (state) => {
    state.status = 'loading'
  },
  AUTH_SUCCESS: (state, token) => {
    state.status = 'success'
    state.token = token
  },
  AUTH_ERROR: (state) => {
    state.status = 'error'
  },
}
```

And the error when I'm trying to logging :

> security.js?0d1f:15 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
> property '$axios' of undefined

Store dispatch call:

```
   this.$store.dispatch('security/AUTH_REQUEST', { email, password
 }).then(() => {
     this.$router.push('/')   })
```

Why 'this' is null ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `app.$axios` or maybe `app.axios`?

Comment: Did you installed it properly btw? Can you share your `package.json` and `nuxt.config.js` please?

Comment: @kissu app is not defined :/ How to get it?
I don't think it's an axios issue, cause "this" is definitively undefined... That's weird...

Answer (score 0):

Solved:  Can't use "this" in arrow functions...